# Rules requiring manual run in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a rule on a folder which executes a JavaScript code whenever a new document enters the folder. The issue is the rule doesn't run automatically when a document enters the folder, but I have to run it manually.

I have tried running the script in background too. If I put a rule on update, that works automatically. The problem is with creation or entering of new documents in the folder. I am using Alfresco community 4.2.f share. 
Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: This should not be happening. How are you adding the file to the folder and how do you have your rule configured (what is the criteria, for example)?

Comment: Basically, whenever a category is added to a document, which is currently in Folder 1, it is moved to the right folder based on the category say to Folder 2. Now Folder 2 executes a script whenever any new document enters it. The problem is this script applied on Folder 2 executes only after running manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot recreate this problem in Alfresco Community Edition 4.2.f. Make sure that:

1. All of the rules are enabled
2. The person putting the document in folder1 has permissions to create new documents in Folder 2.
3. The criteria for the rules are valid
4. The script in Folder 2 is not actually running. The best way to validate this is by turning on the server-side JavaScript debugger by editing $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties and setting log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.AlfrescoRhinoScriptDebugger=on

Alternatively, for #4, you could change to an out-of-the-box action, like another Move that would move the document to Folder 3. That's what my test does. If that works for you like it does for me, you would be able to narrow down your troubleshooting to a problem with the custom script.

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks a lot. I carried out all the steps. For the 4th one, I wrote a test script to move the document to Folder 3 on entering Folder 2. That does work. So, I guess, there is something wrong in my custom script which needs me to run it manually to execute the particular action.

Comment: In the script, I am creating a new html doc and then carrying out a lucene search to find documents with a particular name (matching name of doc just moved) in the same folder, in which the document is located. On further analyzing, I see that the html doc is successfully created but the lucene search part needs the rule to be run manually.

Answer (score 0):

when running scripts fired by rules you can't rely on search for the new doc since indexing isn't finished when the script runs. If SOLR is configured as search engine, indexing is executed async from outside the repository every 15 secs. You already may know that you can get the name from the script node?

Comment: Thanks @Heiko for the reply. If the search executes every 15 sec, what would be the best way to search the document which triggers the rule and make it show up in the search results ?

Comment: you don't need search at all for that use case. If you create a new node (your html) the method returns already the new ScriptNode. Please post your scriptcode to give you advise/hints.